# I want to wrap cursor when mouse gets to an edge

Tags: xorg, mouse, cursor

I used an app on another $y$tem that moved the cursor to the opposite edge (left for right, top for bottom) when it touched an edge.  I can't find anything like it on Ubuntu.

Comment: What does `$y$tem` mean?

Comment: Micro$oft i.e. Microsoft

Comment: With that, the first sentence would be "I used an app on another Microsoft that moved..." Could you edit the question? (I can do it, if you confirm the above.) Nice question, by the way!